# How do I create an SQL retrial for this purpose?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a database for a banking enterprise with this relational schema:

[image: relational schema]

I have came across the following question:

"Provide an SQL retrieval pertaining to an aspect of your bank's activities. Include multi table joins, formatting and conditional retrievals."

As a result of this, I am trying to provide an SQL retrieval where I can find customer names and addresses who have an average account balance between 10,000 and 15,000. Though my limited knowledge is preventing me from doing so. I am trying to prepare a statement which comprises of the two following characteristics:
1. Has multi table joins.
2. Has conditional retrials.

So far I have:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, AccountID, AVG (AccountBalance)
FROM Employee, Account
GROUP BY EmployeeID
HAVING AVG (AccountBalance) BETWEEN
   (SELECT MAX(AVG(MIN AccountBalance))
    FROM Account ...
```

Though I believe the above is not valid.

Any help?

Comment: `retrials` or `retrievals`?

Comment: Yes. Retrievals is what I was meant to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're doing some sort of tutorial, so i try to give you some help in detail. Let's go through what you have. This is the first part of your query:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, AccountID, AVG (AccountBalance)
FROM Employee, Account
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

First, if you want to find Customer names why are you querying Employee?
Second, the FROM clause `FROM Employee, Account` will give you any combination of rows from Employee and Account, aka a Cross Join. But i quess you want to relate the information to each other. 
So what you have to do is: 
Step 1: exchange Employee for Customer

```
SELECT CustomerID, AccountID, AVG (AccountBalance)
FROM Customer, Account
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

Step 2: Create a JOIN between Customer and Account to relate Accounts to Customers.

```
SELECT CustomerID, AccountID, AVG (AccountBalance)
FROM Customer c
    JOIN Account a ON a.CustomerID=c.CustomerID
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

If you try to execute this query, you will run into an error though. This is because you have only CustomerID in the GROUP BY clause but you have also AccountID in the SELECT clause. According to your schema you may have multiple accounts for each customer. So the GROUP BY CustomerID will give you exactly one row for each CustomerID. Now the SQL Server cannot know which AccountID he shall return (because there may be several). That's why the error occurs. The third Column, AVG(AccountBalance) will not throw an error because it contains an aggregate function. The AVG will calculate the average AccountBalance for all Accounts associated to a Customer and will therefore also return exactly one value per CustomerID. So you have to omit the AccountID:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, AVG (a.AccountBalance)
FROM Customer c
    JOIN Account a ON a.CustomerID=c.CustomerID
GROUP BY c.CustomerID
```

This query will execute. You may have noticed that i used Aliases for the tables (a and c) which makes it easier to read the code, especially if it gets more complex with equally named columns in different tables.

So far, you have the average balance of all accounts of a customer for each customer. Now you have to apply the condition "BETWEEN 10.000 AND 15.000" to the result. What you tried is already the right path - you have to apply the condition to the GROUP result and therefore you have to use a HAVING clause.

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, AVG (a.AccountBalance)
FROM Customer c
    JOIN Account a ON a.CustomerID=c.CustomerID
GROUP BY c.CustomerID
HAVING AVG (a.AccountBalance) BETWEEN 10000 AND 15000
```

That's it. Note that BETWEEN includes the borders, so an average account balance of 10000 and 15000 will be included in the result.

You can now add other columns from customer table but make sure you include them in the GROUP BY clause if you want to use them in the SELECT.

Comment: I really appreciate the help. This was greatly beneficial for my understanding. Thank you.